# SSRS Excel output sorting image problem

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, reportviewer

When exporting my simple data report to Excel (Using ReportViewer in localmode) I can sort the table data fine but I have images in all of the rows and they do not sort with the data.

My basic setup is a C# class that provides a List<> of a data type with a few columns and a byte[] image in it as an object data source.

I just dragged an image item into the table and set it up as from Database and MIME type jpeg.

Anyone know how I can enable sorting of my Excel output?

Thanks,

Phil

Edit:

I'm trying to sort via selecting the cells and then going Sort. Not using the filter button.

I'm Using Excel 2007.

Unfortunatly the images are mini graphs that represent quickly what each row means and are really vital when looking through the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think this is possible, as images do not attach to cells but instead positioned fixed distance from the left and top of the spreadsheet. This is Excel behaviour, not related to SSRS itself producing the spreadsheet. It's certainly not possible in 2003 and below, but I've not tried Excel 2007.

Possibly you could get SSRS to export hyperlinks to the images instead of the images themselves, in which case you could sort the data without orphaning the image references.

Answer (score 0):

odd.  i just exported a report of mine that has images and they sort fine.  are you using the filter button or are you just selecting the cells and click the sort button?

Comment: Selecting cells and using sort. Could you describe how the images are used in your report. I've got them as one per row in a Table of data.